# Efficiency of the OLS estimator

Tags: self-study, least-squares, efficiency

I have this linear regression:
$y_{i}=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + u_{i}$ with $i=\{1..n\}$.

Say $\hat{\beta}_{1}$ is the OLS estimator of $\beta_{1}$. $\hat{\beta}_{1}$ is BLUE since the Gauss Markov assumptions hold.

Now I am asked to show that $\tilde{\beta}_{1}=\frac{y_{n}-y_{1}}{x_{n}-x_{1}}$ is less efficient than the OLS estimator.

Say $u_{i}\sim iid $ then
$\text{Var}(\tilde{\beta}_{1})=(\frac{1}{x_{n}-x_{1}})^2\times(\text{Var}(u_{n})-\text{Var}(u_{1}))=0$.

So $\text{Var}(\tilde{\beta}_{1})<\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}_{1})$ which contradict the fact that $\hat{\beta}_{1}$ is BLUE. So obviously the assumption that $u_{i}\sim iid$ is wrong. Why?

Comment: Is the variance of the difference between two random variables the difference of their variances?

Comment: Oh I agree that if the two random variables were dependent then you would have to add the 2*cov(un,u1). But here I am asking about the case when the error terms are independent. Or maybe that's impossible?

Comment: Whether the variables are dependent or independent, variance of the difference between them is not the difference of their variances.

Comment: Is the variance of the difference between two independent random variables the difference of their variances? You should be able to answer that without looking anything up.

Comment: How/Should I mark this as answered?